# In Coursera Algorithms I course, "error: package edu.princeton.cs.algs4 does not exist"

Tags: java

I'm trying to complete the first assignment of the Coursera course [Algorithms I](https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-to-algorithms). As I'm using Linux, I followed the instructions on http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/linux/ and created a `~/algs4` directory. The test programs seem to work; for example, the command

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ java-algs4 edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw
```

generates the image below.

[image]

Next, I'm trying to run a test program in a subdirectory of `~/algs4`:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;

public class PercolationTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

However, if I try to compile this I get the following errors:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/algs4/PercolationTest$ javac PercolationTest.java
PercolationTest.java:3: error: package edu.princeton.cs.algs4 does not exist
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
                             ^
PercolationTest.java:4: error: package edu.princeton.cs.algs4 does not exist
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;
                             ^
2 errors
```

This way of importing does seem consistent with what is explained on http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/, so I'm having trouble seeing what I did wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to compile all classes on the classpath with the `-cp` argument to `javac`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following the examples on http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/, I appended `-algs4` to both the `javac` and `java` commands. Now it seems to work:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/algs4/PercolationTest$ javac-algs4 PercolationTest.java
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/algs4/PercolationTest$ java-algs4 PercolationTest
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Most developers prefer an IDE to write and compile code, by the way

Comment: @cricket_007 Experienced developers that is. There is a lot of merit for beginners to do things manually - to understand what an IDE will do for you.  And keep in mind: eclipse is still a complex product. I think most people learning a new programming language have enough to look into already; so I wouldnt add the burden of exploring eclipse to that bill (unless one has used it in the past).

Comment: @GhostCat I agree we all start somewhere. I think that a Princeton course would teach one around an IDE at somepoint, though. At least they provide helper scripts to compile&run the code

Answer (score -1):

I am probably late to the party, but sharing my experience in case someone else experiences the same issue.

As comments mentioned, I wanted to use my IDE(intellij) for my assignments. I spent hours figuring out to use algs4.jar and nothing seemed to work.

This is probably not the best way to solve your issue, but I would rather download the "pre-configured" folder to start. Download hello.zip and start from there. This is the suggested way from the course anyways.

Hope this helps some people.

https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/mac/

[image]